# Reference required on ICE candidates extensions attribute names and values

Tags: webrtc, stun

ICE candidates info, when sent to the peer, can optionally have extension attributes. However, there is no IANA registry where these extension attributes are registered.  An example of ICE candidate generated by Chrome is:

```
 candidate:565418629 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.5.12 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag g9E6 network-id 1
```

The extensions here are: **generation** with a value of 0, **ufrag** with a value of gE6 and **network-id** with a value of 1. Is there some IANA registry, RFC or any reference of the extension attributes which can be expected and the allowed value while parsing a ICE candidate? In the absence of any IANA registrations, how is one expected to parse a SDP candidate with extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. generation comes from [jingle](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0176.html), the ufrag is the same as the ice-ufrag of the sdp. Network-id is a chrome thing.

The [specification says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-15.1) you shall ignore things you don't understand

Comment: Yes. While "ufrag" is obvious, is interoperability compromised in any way by ignoring extensions not understood.  "Network-id is a chrome thing". Can it be safely ignored when inter-operating with other browsers?